# Armature custom properties?

Tags: armature, properties

[image]
Custom properties added to the armature tab do not appear on the item tab of the 3d viewport side bar, unlike the object tab and the bones tab.
I’m curious about how to check armature custom properties and examples of using them.

Comment: Codewise if `ob` is object `ob.data` is armature and `ob.pose.bones["Foo"[` is active pose bone, the custom properties are `ob["prop"]` (object) `ob.data["prop"]` (armature) and `ob.pose.bones["Foo"]["prop"}` on the pose bone.  The custom property of a "data" part ie mesh, armature lattice are displayed generally only in the data properties.

Comment: Oh, codewise! I understood. There's nothing to use for general rig manipulation.